# Find the font size in pixels of selected text in PSD

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

There is probably something simple that I am missing here, but how do I find the font size in pixels of selected text in a PSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a selection of the text by Alt + Left Clicking the text's thumbnail image. Make a new layer. The Width and Height will show up in the Properties panel under "W" and "H".

Adobe programs set the width and height based on the texts bounding box. That is why the dimensions will not be what you expect in the Properties.

[image: sample]

Not sure if there is an easier way.

Comment: That will work well enough for what I need to accomplish. Thanks